# Two sections in screen and change height via swipe in react native

Tags: react-native, swipe, gesture

We have two sections of screen and section one height + section two = total height of screen. If user swipe Up or down from middle button base on that both section will be decrease  and increase in a height.
i have attached screen shot here.

[image]